# ES6 Dynamic importing with namespace?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, dynamic-import

When using dynamic imports, can I define what I want to import like regular imports?

For example:

```
import Person from '/classes.js'
```

As dynamic:

```
await import('Person from /classes.js') //Incorrect obviously
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dynamic imports will hand you everything from within the module. You can use destructuring the extract the pieces you want.

```
const { Person } = await import('/classes.js');
```

Comment: In this example, will the rest of classes.js be discarded from memory?

Comment: @Mojimi Assuming nothing else references them then yes. Any value which is not referenced by another value in the object graph will be dropped.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this when you need to import some specific file.

```
const moduleSpecifier = '/classes.js';
import(moduleSpecifier)
.then(someModule => someModule.myFucntion());
```